# Why does one Gameobject work when i try to destroy the other one, but it doesnt work the other way around?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, destroy

I want a Gameobject to delete itself and a ifferent Gameobject with the tag 'Card'
The Script is attached to both of them, so i expected it to work for both, but just one of them does it. I used this code
The Code is called when i drop the Card so only one of the cards runs the code at a time

```
Destroy(gameObject);
Destroy(GameObject.FindWithTag("Card"));
```

I also tried adding
`gameObject.transform.SetAsLastSibling();`
to see if it would change anything, but it didn't

Comment: What do you mean by the script is attached to both .. so both delete themselves at the same time? How/When exactly is this called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by creating an array with the gameObjects that i want to destroy and then destoying them in order

```
GameObject[] destroy = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Card");
        for (var i = 0; i < destroy.Length; i++)
        {
            Destroy(destroy[i]);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

this line of executes inside the gameObject

```
Destroy(gameObject);
Destroy(GameObject.FindWithTag("Card"));
```

but you are destroying the gameObject before it executes the second line of code it should be like this

```
Destroy(GameObject.FindWithTag("Card"));
Destroy(gameObject);
```

Comment: I tried this, but still just one of the gameobjects does it